# How to make two virtual hosts work in same server to integrate Onlyoffice - DocumentServer

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-18.04, nextcloud, onlyoffice

Nextcloud version : 16.0.4
Operating system and version : 18.04
Apache or nginx version  Nginx 1.14
PHP version : 7.2

The issue you are facing:

I have a LEMP instance with ubuntu 18.04 ...

My /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 nextcloud.eduardo.com
127.0.0.1 onlyoffice.eduardo.com
```

I have a working instance of nextcloud in: nextcloud.eduardo.com, and i want that document server would run in onlyoffice.eduardo.com...

I have installed document server using deb package as your documentation says....
Also would like that default server would be localhost pointing to /var/www/html as usual...

I can get it to work as i dont know how to setup document server with nginx...

Here is all my configuration nginx in /etc/nginx
https://drive.google.com/drive/u/1/folders/1I2ZiRUKqmm8u5U5TsqyoOKUvfTwY-SPA

Comment: It is not good idea to share link to nginx folder from google drive. Please, attach all required files to this issue.

Comment: How can i imporve this ? nginx has many files nginx conf folder, nginx sites avalaible, and nginx sites enabled... I perfectly assume that folder is public, in fact i have shared with other forums either....

Comment: It is not easy to download all configs from google drive, and then to have reference to some line.
And all people, how want to help you, must to download all configs and open each of then.
You need to attach only your configs: config for nextcloud and confg for onlyoffice.

Comment: Its the only thing i have configured... there are all config files that are not heavy. So a person that want to help, probably would take a look to some different files and want to spot the possible errors.. Thay dont even need to download the file.Perhaps id delete some file that is important for nginx.